# Find geo coordinate by a coordinate and an angle

Tags: geometry, spherical-coordinates

I need some help with this problem.

I have a GPS coordinate and an angle in degrees. I need a new GPS coordinate x km away from the point I already have.

Degree is counted clockwise and y-axis is pointing at north.

[image]

Anybody that can help me out with a formula?

Comment: Are your coordinates in northing and easting?  If so then your new northing and easting are reduced by $5 \cos 55$ and $5 \sin 55$ respectively.

Comment: Sorry if i'm asking something wrong but don't I need to take into account that these are spherical coordinates I'm working with?

Comment: Are your coordinates in longitude and latitude, then?

Comment: Yes they are, the known point is a gps coordinate in lat and long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except near the poles, for a distance as short as 5 km, one can treat the coordinate system as orthogonal, though not orthonormal (to stretch the meaning of these terms a bit).  Denote the known point's coordinates by $\phi$ and $\lambda$.  Then the unknown point's coordinates (taking north and east as positive) are

$$
\phi' = \phi - \frac{900 \sin 55}{\pi R \cos \lambda}
$$
$$
\lambda' = \lambda - \frac{900 \cos 55}{\pi R}
$$

where $R \doteq 6370$ is the Earth's radius in km.  The $900/\pi R$ comes from $5/R$ generating the subtended angle in radians, multiplied by $180/\pi$ to get degrees.  So, for instance, if one starts at $\phi = 2, \lambda = 49$ (near Paris), and travels $5$ km at heading $235$ (as in the diagram you provided), one ends up at

$$
\phi' \doteq 2 - 0.05615 = 1.94385
$$
$$
\lambda' \doteq 49 - 0.02580 = 48.97420
$$

Is that good enough?  Near the poles it's a bit more involved.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try this out and let you know if it gives me a usable coordinate

Comment: I've rewritten your formula as ø - (5/6371*(180/PI))*(sin(55)/cos(a)) and the same for a.
But I needed to add -45 degree to 55 to get it almost correct but it's still off by about 12 degrees from what I've calculated on paper

Comment: img: [link](http://tinypic.com/r/2qwmpf7/8)

Comment: my code: [link](http://i62.tinypic.com/23r4q6x.jpg)